Determine if particular job within a workflow is ran with GitHub Actions
The current workflows are as such:

PR created -> CI workflow -> Build job -> Test job | Benchmarks job

CI workflow -> Reporter workflow


What I'm aiming for is to have the Reporter workflow only run when Benchmarks job is requested & again when completed and successful. Unfortunately this has to be a separate workflow, as it (Reporter workflow) has access to our tokens and so we cannot let PRs trigger it. Hence, Reporter workflow relies upon workflow_run.
Historically, Test job & Benchmarks job were separate workflows, making this a lot simpler for Reporter workflow to watch. However, this was a bit wasteful (both ran Build job prior to running themselves) and noisy in the case of failures, hence the switch.
Benchmarks job is unfortunately conditional, and it won't always run. Therefore, we can't always run Reporter workflow. I was hoping for something along the lines of github.event.workflow_run.<job name>...., but that doesn't seem to exist in any capacity that I can see.
How can I filter jobs of a workflow by the jobs of another workflow? Especially when it won't have the same context as CI workflow, and so I can't simply copy/paste the filtering over to Reporter workflow.
To show the historic & non-working setup now:
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['Benchmarks']
    types:
      - requested
      - completed

jobs:
  report_start:
    if: ${{ github.event.action == 'requested' }}
    ...

  report_end:
    if: ${{ github.event.action == 'completed' && github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    ...

As mentioned, this would not work, I need to filter this further by job within that workflow.

Edit: What I ended up doing is duplicating the filter that determines whether Benchmarks job runs to Reporter workflow. It's a bit fragile and certainly less than ideal, but I suppose does the job.
Would still like a to see a better solution here, what jobs are ran (or queued to run) should be exposed from a workflow, IMO.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/share-github-jobs-data#share-data-across-jobs-in-different-workflows

@avifen Interesting! That indeed might be what I'm after, somehow that never appeared in my searches. Will have to give it a shot, thanks!

Didn't try it, you might discover you need token to set

That should be okay if it's the consumer (Reporter) that needs the token set, as that can be controlled.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that solutions belong in answers, not edits to the question. Likewise, code formatting is for code only, not emphasis or names of actions/buttons/commands in GUI programs.

That wasn't a solution, but a way around the issue. "Welcome to Stack Overflow" is also pretty rude considering I've been on the site for 3 years... and not incorrectly reformatting while I was at it.
